# so i was working with session and it showed maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python, django

I was working with the session and it showed maximum recursion depth was exceeded.

**basket.py**

```py
class basket():
    def __init__(self,request) :
        self.session=request.session
        basket=self.session.get('skey')
        if 'skey' not in request.session:
            basket=self.session['skey']={}
        self.basket=basket
```

And what does this line says - `self.basket=basket`.

**context_processor.py**

```py
from .Basket import basket

def basket(request):
    return{
        'bas':basket(request)
    }
```

**settings.py**

```py
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR/'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'app.views.category',
                'basket.context_processor.basket',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

**Error traceback:**

```
PS C:\Users\hp\core> python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
October 10, 2022 - 23:22:00
Django version 4.1.1, using settings 'core.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Internal Server Error: /

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
        response = get_response(request)
      File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
        response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\hp\core\app\views.py", line 8, in home
        return render(request,'home.html',{'product':products})
      File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 24, in render
        content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
      File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
        return template.render(context, request)
      File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 62, in render
        return self.template.render(context)
      File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 173, in render
        with context.bind_template(self):
      File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\contextlib.py", line 135, in __enter__
        return next(self.gen)
      File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\context.py", line 254, in bind_template
        updates.update(processor(self.request))
      File "C:\Users\hp\core\basket\context_processor.py", line 5, in basket
        'bas':basket(request)
      File "C:\Users\hp\core\basket\context_processor.py", line 5, in basket
        'bas':basket(request)
      File "C:\Users\hp\core\basket\context_processor.py", line 5, in basket
        'bas':basket(request)
      [Previous line repeated 951 more times]
    RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
    [10/Oct/2022 23:22:05] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 2166512
```

Comment: You class-name `basket` and variable name `basket` are identical.

Comment: Right.  In the function `basket` in `context_processor.py`, when you call `basket`, you are recursively calling that same function.  You have deleted the `basket` that you imported.

Comment: still not working